# How to get Low Search results based on the category of a related item?

Tags: relationships, low-search

I have doctor channel and a locations channel. Each doctor has one or more related locations. Each location has one or more categories assigned.

For example, Location1 has Region1 and Region2 categories assigned to it, and Location1 is related to Doctor1.

Is there a way to return a list of Doctor search results with doctors who work in Region1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low Search cannot do this out of the box, but you can achieve it with either a [custom filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/create) or an [extension](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/hooks).

For example, if you use the [low_search_pre_search hook](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/hooks#low_search_pre_search), you can read the Region category, query the database for Location entries, and assign those entries to a [Relationships filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#relationships) parameter.

Note that I could create the extension (or custom filter) for you, for a fee. Just [drop me a note](http://gotolow.com/contact) if you're interested in that.

Comment: I'll send you a message. I think a custom filter or extension is exactly what we need.